# How to switch xml layout ordering

Tags: java, android, layout

I was wondering how to change the the layout of an xml file based on a conditional.  So lets say we have a layout as such..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"

>
```

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/app_background"
 android:padding="5dip"
 >

<ListView android:id="@+id/xlist"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"

            android:divider="@drawable/listdivider"
            android:dividerHeight="19dp"

           />
  <TextView 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:background="@drawable/listdivider"
              android:layout_height="19dp"
              android:visibility="gone"
             android:id="@+id/dividerline"
              />
  <ListView android:id="@+id/ylist"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
             android:divider="@drawable/listdivider"
            android:dividerHeight="19dp"

           />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

So you set two Variables as listviews, and based on the xml the "xlist" will appear before the "ylist".  But for my code I would like to switch the ordering of this view if a certain condition is met.  So how would I go about switching the order so that if a certain condition is met, the "ylist" will appear above the "xlist"?

Comment: I guess you mean programmatically, right?

Comment: correct so like 
    Xadapter = xadapter;
    Yadapter = yadapter;
    xlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.xlist);
    ylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ylist);

Comment: Ok then you don't need the XML tag, neither the OOP tag since your question has nothing to do with OOP proper :)

Comment: Well, android layouts are in fact XML files, and I am setting them using java which is OOP....

Comment: Welcome to SO :) Be as much specific as you can in your tags. Your question is not about XML and it's not about OOP. In fact, it's not even about Java. It's about Android and layouts.

Comment: My above code is in XML, and I'm programming my android application in Java so it has everything to do with OOP.  I'm really not following you..  I can see how XML might be misleading but, are you saying that even though it is programmed in Java, I should only tag android?  Because If i were to just tag android, then I figured that it doesn't specify it to the programming aspect.  Not trying to attack you or anything just trying to get a better understanding of how I should "tag" questions,  I am kind of new to SO.

Comment: First, SO is a **programming** Q&A site, so no need to put tags to specify your question is about programming. Second, as I said above, you must be specific about your question. I understand your PoV about that you can put "XML", "OOP" tags because your question has those topics too, but following the same logic, you can also add "mobile device", "tablet", "phone", "Graham Bell", "death", "religion"... and following you can add any tag because one way of the other it will be related. The question is to pick the more specifc tags **directly** related to your question.

Comment: Ok that makes sense I figured the more tags the more likely my question would be answered.

Comment: Not really. The more *specific* your tags are, the more likely your question will be answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way to do that is to put each view in its own xml file.
Then at runtime attach them to the linearLayout in the desired order.

Say your layout file is: main.xml
and you have list_a.xml, list_b.xml, and textview.xml

in your activity:

```
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
 Super.onCreate(bundle);
 setContentView(R.layout.main);
 LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
 LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
 if (condition) {
 inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_a, layout);
 inflater.inflate(R.layout.textview, layout);
 inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_b, layout);


} else { 
     inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_b, layout);
 inflater.inflate(R.layout.textview, layout);
 inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_a, layout);
 }
 }
```

Comment: Yes, this is a better solution, definitely. Good call.

Comment: OK, good solution, but I was kind of looking for an easier solution.  Like for overlapping layouts, you can assign each layout a "z" value, which would be easy to change in code because you can just change the 2 layouts z value from 0 to 1.  Is there nothing like that for list layouts?

Comment: You can just use tow different xml files for the layout and chose the suitable one on the condition instead. I'm not sure exactly why are you doing this in the first place

Comment: Kind of hard to explain why I'm doing this but essentially, if one of my lists contains a certain item without another, the second list would need to be listed first rather than the second.  So I have two adapter classes, and lets say "X" needs to be displayed at the top.  So if my first list has no item "x" in it but has a "y" and if the second list contains an item "x" the view's need to be switched because "x" needs to be listed first.

Answer (score 0):

Never did that but this should work:

```
public void switchViewOrder(final ViewGroup parent, final int view1Id, final int view2Id) {

    View view1 = null;
    int view1pos = -1;
    View view2 = null;
    int view2pos = -1;

    int count = parent.getChildCount();
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        View cur = parent.getChildAt(i);
        if (view1Id == cur.getId()) {
            view1 = cur;
        } else if (view2Id == cur.getId()) {
            view2 = cur;
        }
    }

    parent.removeViewAt(view1pos);
    parent.removeViewAt(view2pos);

    parent.addView(view1, view2pos);
    parent.addView(view2, view1pos);
}
```

I leave to you to add proper null-and-the-like checks.